# Plotting functions defined via NIntegrate. Too slow

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, special-functions, regions, parametric-functions

I have the following two functions `xs[u,v]` and `ys[u,v]` defined through numerical integration of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and $\theta$, as shown below

```
α[u_, v_] :=  Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, -u v] -  v Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2,-u v]
β[u_, v_] := (1 + u) Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -u v] -   u v Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3, -u v]
θ[u_, v_] := u + v


 xs[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[α[u1, 0] Cos[θ[u1, 0]], {u1, 0, u}] - NIntegrate[β[u, v1] Sin[θ[u, v1]], {v1, 0, v}]

 ys[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[α[u1, 0] Sin[θ[u1, 0]], {u1, 0, u}] + NIntegrate[β[u, v1] Cos[θ[u, v1]], {v1, 0, v}]
```

Now, I wish to plot the parametric region defined by these functions, so I use

```
  RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]}, {{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}]]
```

But it takes extremely long times to get the picture (of the order of hours). So I guess the way I posed the problem is highly inefficient. Any tips how to seep it up ?

Thanks.

Comment: you might have to use `DiscretizeRegion` or such. Since you are doing numerical integration, the `RegionPlot` is sampling too many points between 0 and 1, and hence probably making zillions of calls to these numerical integration making is very slow. I do not use these functions much myself, but this is my guess what is happening.

Comment: By defining `B[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 1 - E^(-I u) + NIntegrate[\[Beta][u, v1] Exp[-I \[Theta][u, v1]], {v1, 0, v}]` you can compute `xs[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := Im[B[u, v]]` and `ys[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := Re[B[u, v]]` at the same time, which may help when using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OP's code ran for ten or fifteen minutes and then I killed it.  Below we use `NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolve` to compute the integrals.  `ParametricNDSolve` caches results, so that if an integral is in the cache, it won't be recomputed.

```
α[u_, v_] := 
 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, -u v] - 
  v Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -u v]
β[u_, v_] := (1 + u) Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -u v] - 
  u v Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3, -u v]
θ[u_, v_] := u + v

ucos = NDSolveValue[
   {y'[u1] == α[u1, 0] Cos[θ[u1, 0]], y[0] == 0},
   y, {u1, 0, 1}];
usin = NDSolveValue[
   {y'[u1] == α[u1, 0] Sin[θ[u1, 0]], y[0] == 0},
   y, {u1, 0, 1}];
vcos = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {y'[v1] == β[u, v1] Cos[θ[u, v1]], y[0] == 0}, 
   y, {v1, 0, 1}, {u}];
vsin = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {y'[v1] == β[u, v1] Sin[θ[u, v1]], y[0] == 0}, 
   y, {v1, 0, 1}, {u}];

xs[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := ucos[u] - vsin[u][v]
ys[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := usin[u] + vcos[u][v]
```

`RegionPlot[]` finishes relatively quickly, though not really fast.

```
RegionPlot[
  ParametricRegion[{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]},
   {{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

`ParametricPlot[]` is quicker, in part because the meshing computes the function on the same `u` for several values of `v` (the integrals for which are cached by `vsin[u]` and `vcos[u]`):

```
ParametricPlot[{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]},
  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

This shows the above without showing the overlap:

```
Show[
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
  ParametricPlot[{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}], 
 Frame -> True]
```

Fixing the overlap must be a major factor in what takes so long with the `ParametricRegion` form.

*Update:*

Actually, two of the integrals may be done symbolically, but it doesn't make that much difference:

```
ClearAll[ucos, usin];
ucos[u_] = Integrate[α[u, 0] Cos[θ[u, 0]], {u, 0, u}];
usin[u_] = Integrate[α[u, 0] Sin[θ[u, 0]], {u, 0, u}];
```

*Update 2:*

Here's a way to remove the crossing boundary, which still exists in  the `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@ParametricPlot[..]` form above, so that `RegionPlot` gives a good picture, in case that is desired (`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` is optional):

```
mesh = (*BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@*)
  MeshRegion[
   MeshCoordinates[#],
   MeshCells[#, 2] (* take the polygons, omit the boundary *)
   ] &@DiscretizeGraphics@
  ParametricPlot[{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}];
RegionPlot[mesh]
```

[image]

It takes only 0.33 sec.

Comment: (+1) `ParametricPlot[{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]]`

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you so much. That timing is low enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 5):

```
α[u_, v_] = Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, -u v] - v Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -u v];
β[u_, v_] = (1 + u) Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -u v] - u v Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3, -u v];
θ[u_, v_] = u + v;
```

Find both `xs` and `ys` at the same time by (1) analytically integrating $\alpha$ and (2) combining the $\beta$-integrals into a single complex integral:

```
B[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 1 - E^(-I u) + 
  NIntegrate[β[u, v1] Exp[-I θ[u, v1]], {v1, 0, v}]
xy[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := Reverse[ReIm[B[u, v]]]

ParametricPlot[xy[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image]